# Providing cell address in formula as a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use VBA to extract information out of a data dump. My approach is to find the trigger strings and extract information from the cell that is activated as a result of that search.

```
Sub ExtractingValues_T1()
Dim ValueLoc As String

Sheets("Sheet1").Select 'This is to select the right sheet
Range("A1").Select 'This is so that when I perform my find, I get results top down

Cells.Find(What:="037 = 2001", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate 'This simply selects the first cell that meets my search requirement

'Below is where I run into trouble
ValueLoc = ActiveCell.Address 'Here, I'm trying to get the address of the cell I need to use a formula on
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Formula = "=RIGHT(ActiveCell, 10)" 'Here I try to use that address in the formula
```

BUT, I get an error. I understand my problem is with my approach and that I can't provide a cell reference as a variable in the way I'm doing it. But what is the correct approach?

Comment: Yes... *.formula = "= A" & i & "+B" & i* lets you have the variable *i* determined by something else... *i* can be from a loop, tied to a text box, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing it slightly differently like below, you should try not to use Select & Activate methods as they very unruly and you might end up with unwanted results, the code below will do what you expect without Selecting anything:

```
Sub ExtractingValues_T1()
Dim foundvalue As Range
'below specified Sheet and Range to look for the value, in this case looking in Column A, amend as required
Set foundvalue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(What:="037 = 2001", After:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not foundvalue Is Nothing Then 'if you found something
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Formula = "=RIGHT(" & foundvalue.Address & ", 10)" 'add the address of the found value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to make some minor changes to conform this to my program but it worked well.

Appreciate your help! and yes, trying to not rely as much on select and activate is something I'm working towards. Wish me luck :)

Comment: @MufaddalM, please could you mark my response as an answer if it has helped? Thanks,... And I'm sure you won't need that much luck as it isn't that difficult to avoid using Select and Activate... :)